# Google Map stay gray on start

Tags: angularjs, html

I built a module that read locations from my DB and present them with markers on the map using Googlemaps APi. currently when the page is load i get a list of location and see the marker on the map but the map is empty (gray screen) and only the Google logo is appear and the Max zoom button.
i didn't succeed to find what is the problem.
this is my code:
map.html:

```
<div class="page map" data-ng-controller="mapCtrl">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading " >
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            Locations
        </h3><!-- panel-title h3 END -->
    </div><!-- panel-heading div END -->
    <div class="panel-body ">
        <div ng-show="no_data">{{main.noDataMsg}}</div><!--if noDataFlag==true show noDataMsg div END-->
        <div ng-show="!no_data">
            <div class="container-fluid noPadding">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-12 noPadding">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search in Map Table" ng-model="searchMapTableData">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div><!-- input-group-addon div END -->
                                </div><!-- input-group div END -->
                            </div><!-- form-group div END -->
                        </form><!-- form div END -->
                    </div><!-- col-md-12 div END -->
                </div><!--row-fluid div END -->
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-4 noPadding">
                        <div class="table_wrapper">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead fsm-sticky-header>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'timestamp'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                                        Time
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'timestamp' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'timestamp' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'latitude'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                                        Latitude
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'latitude' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'latitude' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'longitude'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                                        Longitude
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'longitude' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                        <span ng-show="sortType == 'longitude' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            <tr  data-ng-repeat="item in locations_data | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse  | filter:matchSearchInput(searchMapTableData)"
                                 ng-class="{'selectedRowMap':$index == selectedRow}"
                                 ng-click="setClickedRow($index)"
                                 context-menu="menuOptions" model="'locations'" ng-model="locations_data"  user-tag tag="{{item.user_tag}}">
                                <td data-ng-click="goToLocation(item)"> {{item.timestamp}} </td>
                                <td data-ng-click="goToLocation(item)">{{item.latitude}} </td>
                                <td data-ng-click="goToLocation(item)"> {{item.longitude}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>

                        </table><!-- table END -->
                        </div>
                        <span class="load_more" lazyload category="locations">{{error_text}}</span>
                    </div><!--col-md-4 div END -->
                    <div class="col-md-8 noPaddingRight" ng-show="!no_data">
                        <div class="map_wrapper">
                        <ui-gmap-google-map control="map" refresh="true" events="map.events" center="center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" language="en"  options="options"  >
                            <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'coords'" idKey="'id'" options="'options'" >
                            </ui-gmap-markers>
                         <ui-gmap-map-control>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="zoomToAllPoints()">MAX ZOOM</button>
                         </ui-gmap-map-control>
                        </ui-gmap-google-map>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- col-md-8 div END -->
                </div><!-- row-fluid div END -->
            </div><!-- container-fluid div END -->
        </div><!-- if noDataFlag== false show bookmarks information div END-->
    </div><!-- panel-body div END -->
</div><!-- panel panel-default div END -->
```

mapCtrl.js:

```
  /**
 * Created by Netalie on 5/3/2016.
 */
angular.module('app').controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, mainTarget, $timeout, uiGmapIsReady, $filter) {

    $scope.category_name = 'locations';
    $scope.locations_data = [];
    $scope.main_array = [];
    $scope.no_data = true;

    $rootScope.$on('targetLoaded', function () {
        //$scope.init();
    });

    $scope.options = {
        width: 520,
        height: 624
    }
    $scope.zoomToAllPoints = function () {
        var markers = $scope.markerData; //some array;

        $scope.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            $scope.bounds.extend(markers[i]);
        }

        uiGmapIsReady.promise().then((function () {
            $timeout($scope.setFitBounds, "100")
        }));

    };

    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.window_height = $(window).height() - 290;
        // console.debug('WINDOW HEIGHT IS: ',$scope.window_height);
        angular.element('.angular-google-map-container').css('height', $scope.window_height + 'px');
        $scope.selectedRow = null;
        $scope.sortType = 'timestamp'; // set the default sort type
        $scope.sortReverse = true;  // set the default sort order
        $scope.searchNetworks = '';     // set the default search/filter term

        //$scope.locations_data = mainTarget.getProperty().locations;
        $scope.noDataFlag = true;


        var markers = [];
        $scope.markerData = [];
        if ($scope.locations_data != undefined) {

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.locations_data.length; i++) {

                var label = "Longitude: " + $scope.locations_data[i].longitude + "\n" +
                    "Latitude: " + $scope.locations_data[i].latitude + "\n" +
                    "Timestamp:" + $scope.locations_data[i].timestamp;

                var marker = {
                    id: $scope.locations_data[i].record_hash,
                    coords: {
                        latitude: $scope.locations_data[i].latitude,
                        longitude: $scope.locations_data[i].longitude
                    },
                    options: {title: label},
                };
                // console.debug('MARKER',marker);
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($scope.locations_data[i].latitude), parseFloat($scope.locations_data[i].longitude));

                $scope.markerData.push(myLatlng);

                markers.push(marker);

            }
        }
        $scope.randomMarkers = markers;
        if ($scope.locations_data != undefined) {
            if ($scope.locations_data.length > 0) {
                $scope.noDataFlag = false;
                $scope.center = {latitude: markers[0].coords.latitude, longitude: markers[0].coords.longitude};
            }
            else {
                $scope.noDataFlag = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $scope.noDataFlag = false;
        }
        $scope.zoomToAllPoints();
    }

    $scope.setClickedRow = function (index) {  //function that sets the value of selectedRow to current index
        $scope.selectedRow = index;
    }
    $scope.goToLocation = function (item) {
        $scope.center = {latitude: item.latitude, longitude: item.longitude};
        // console.debug('goToLocation', $scope.center);
        angular.extend($scope.map, {zoom: 15});
        //$scope.map = {zoom: 15};
    }


    $scope.center = {latitude: 45, longitude: -73}
    //$scope.init();
    $scope.map = {zoom: 15};


    $scope.setFitBounds = function () {
        $scope.map.getGMap().fitBounds($scope.bounds);
    };

    //function for run filter on specific columns in the table 
    $scope.matchSearchInput = function (query) {
        if ($scope.locations_data.length > 0) {
            return function (item) {
                return ($filter('uppercase')($scope.returnEmptyString(item.timestamp)).match($filter('uppercase')(query)) ||
                $filter('uppercase')($scope.returnEmptyString(item.latitude)).match($filter('uppercase')(query)) ||
                $filter('uppercase')($scope.returnEmptyString(item.longitude)).match($filter('uppercase')(query)));
            }
        }
    };
    //function check if string is null and return empty string
    $scope.returnEmptyString = function (str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return '';
        }

        return str;
    };


    // listen for new_data event from the lazy load directive
    $scope.$on('mainArrayLoaded', function (event, args) {
        // console.debug("MAIN ARRAY LOADED",args);
        $scope.locations_data = $scope.main_array;
        $scope.init();
        $scope.no_data = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: check you browser console log to find out any possible error and share only minimum line of code

Comment: i do not have any errors except warning on googleApiKey, However when i click on F12 and close the browser console the map is load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was that the page was loaded before the map so i added

```
$scope.map.refresh();
```

into

```
uiGmapIsReady.promise().then
```

function